# Бот не отвечает на сообщение

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

```
class FSMAdmin(StatesGroup):
    report1 = State()
    report1end = State()

@dp.message_handler(text=('Отчет 1'), state=None)
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply('Отправь отчет')


@dp.message_handler(state=FSMAdmin.report1)
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message, state=FSMContext):
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=photo20)
    await message.reply('hello')
```

При отправке сообщения после Отчет 1 ничего не происходит[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и ничего

Comment: А почему должно что-то происходить? Сообщение отправляется и функция завершается, вам нужно перейти в следующий стейт

Comment: А. Просто по гайду смотрю там в 0 стэйте функция next() не ставиться